# Array wordpress php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to create a portfolio in wordpress.
It is working properly but I would like to see the categories of the portfolio in h3 under the h2 title.

Other question.

Now the link will only work on the title h2, I wish it were all over the caption as link.

any advice on the code are welcome! Thank you so much

```html
<?php 
       $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
       $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio-categories' );      
          if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
 
              $links = array();
 
              foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                  $links[] = $term->name;
              }
 
              $tax_links = join( " ", str_replace(' ', '-', $links));          
              $tax = strtolower($tax_links);
          else : 
       $tax = '';     
          endif; 
    
       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    
    echo '<div class="row-masonry">';
    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo '<div class="well portfolio-item no-gutter">';
    echo '<div class="thumbnail no-gutter">'. get_the_post_thumbnail() .'</div>';
    echo '<div class="caption">';
    echo '<div class="vertical-align">';
     $link = get_the_permalink();
                echo "<a href=$link>";
                echo '<h2>'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';
   
                I want to see here the portfolio image category in h3
  
                echo "</a>";
    echo '</div>'; /*close caption*/
    echo '</div>'; /*close caption*/
    echo '</div>'; 
    
    echo '</div>'; 
    endwhile;
    echo '</div>'; 
    echo '</div>'; 
    echo '</div>'; 
    
  ?>
      
 

 
  </div><!-- #page -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. You can google how to get the category for a post. It will yield your answer - but this will work.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio-categories' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :

    $links = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $links[] = $term->name;
    }

    $tax_links = join( " ", str_replace(' ', '-', $links));
    $tax = strtolower($tax_links);
else :
    $tax = '';
endif;

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    echo '<div class="row-masonry">';
    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo '<div class="well portfolio-item no-gutter">';
    echo '<div class="thumbnail no-gutter">'. get_the_post_thumbnail() .'</div>';
    echo '<div class="caption">';
    echo '<div class="vertical-align">';
    $link = get_the_permalink();
    echo "<a href=$link>";
    echo '<h2>'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';

    // GET THE CATEGORY -- Returns an array of all categories
    // $categories = get_the_category();
    $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio-categories' ); // for custom taxnomies

    // If not an empty array then show the first category set
    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        echo "<h3>" . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) ."</h3>";
    }



                echo "</a>";
                echo '</div>'; /*close caption*/
                echo '</div>'; /*close caption*/
                echo '</div>'; 

                echo '</div>';
endwhile;
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

?>




</div><!-- #page -->
```

Comment: Try this `$categories = get_the_terms( $id, 'portfolio-categories' );`

Comment: @Nicola No problem. That is why this community is here. Now if you wouldn't mind giving me the answer... THANKS :D

Comment: @Nicola please click to accept this answer. It's the big tick next to the answer.